# Javascript - Q&A Hide and Unhide Question Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and working on one of my first projects. I am working on a Q&A section, which would have three Divs each containing a question and when you click on the div I would like the answer to pop down and when clicked again for it to go away.

---

So far this is what I have.

What should I do to clean up my code and what steps should I take to make it so when the answer is shown it has some ease in and ease out? Thank you.

```js
const question = document.querySelector('.question1')

console.log(question);

question.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (question.querySelector('.divider').classList.contains('hidden')) {
    question.querySelector('.divider').classList.remove('hidden');
    question.querySelector('.answer').classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    question.querySelector('.divider').classList.add('hidden');
    question.querySelector('.answer').classList.add('hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #cceabb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
}

.question {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.divider {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3f3f4457;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Questions and Answers</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="question question1">
      <h2 class="question-text">do you accept all major credit cards?</h2>
      <div class="divider hidden"></div>
      <p class="answer hidden">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae minima corrupti unde eum rerum aperiam nulla aliquam similique explicabo assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="question question2">
      <h2 class="question-text">do you support local farmers?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="question question3">
      <h2 class="question-text">do you use organic ingredients?</h2>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using jquery is not a problem, you can easily do this.

```js
            $(function () {
                $('.question').click(function () {
                    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggleClass("hidden");
                });
            });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #cceabb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
}

.question {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 16px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: .8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.divider {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3f3f4457;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Questions and Answers</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <main>
            <div target="1" class="question">
                <h2 class="question-text">do you accept all major credit cards?</h2>
                <div id="div1" class="hidden">
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae minima corrupti unde eum rerum aperiam nulla aliquam similique explicabo assumenda.</p>
               </div>
                </div>
            <div target="2" class="question">
                <h2 class="question-text">do you support local farmers?</h2>
                <div id="div2" class="hidden">
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <p class="answer"> Answer of question 2 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div target="3" class="question">
                <h2 class="question-text">do you use organic ingredients?</h2>
                <div id="div3" class="hidden">
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <p class="answer"> Answer of question 3 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you! Would adding a transition in CSS be able to add ease in and out?